# Lucene MemoryIndex: Add Lucene Field

Tags: java, lucene

I would like to use lucene's [MemoryIndex](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_1/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html#addField%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream,%20float%29) (using 4.7.1) but I need to be able to add lucene [Fields](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) so that I can use things like the integer field or a StringField.

I know this is possible in RAMDirectory by adding a Document which can contain Lucene Fields but is this possible in MemoryIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly add fields to the index, just not `Field`s.  It's fairly simple for `StringField` and `TextField`, since there is a nice convenience method for you to use.  For a `StringField`, something like:

```
index.addField("thestring", text, new KeywordAnalyzer());
```

For a `TextField`:

```
index.addField("sometext", text, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_47));
```

For an `IntField` and other numerics, you'll need to produce the tokenstream yourself.  [`NumericTokenStream`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/NumericTokenStream.html) is the class of interest here:

```
NumericTokenStream stream = new NumericTokenStream();
stream.setIntValue(myInt);
index.addField("aninteger", stream);
```

Comment: It seems like a lot of unnecessary work compared to using a RAMDirectory object especially when I only need to index a single document at a time.

Comment: I believe that providing the granularity to control the contents of the `TokenStream` directly is part of the purpose of the class.  In addition to the improvements to performance.  If you want a class the behaves exactly as an index saved to the file system, just stored in memory instead, then yes, `RAMDirectory` is the right choice.